# Load/Save XML special characters

Tags: xml, special-characters, xelement

My XML file has some french characters.

```
<fr>Non prêt pour recevoir l&apos;échantillon.</fr>
```

After XElement::Load() and then save it without any change. it becomes

```
<fr>Non prêt pour recevoir l'échantillon.</fr>
```

How did this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: What's the problem? That is an unnecessary escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only characters required escape sequences for tag content are `&`, `<` and `>`. Thus XElement produces valid XML.

If your code requires this escape to persist it's, probably, not very good, since it's requires non-standard behaviour.

But if you wish to preserve exact content you can use a [CDATA section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection).

As for your comment, I guess it's not possible to use CDATA if you not in control of incoming XML. Possibly you only option then is to either process XML as a text file, or to replace `'` to `&apos;` (and other escape sequences) after XML modification, after converting it to a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This XML is going to be consumed by a 3rd party software and I have to keep it as it is. How to use a CDATA section without touching the XML itself?

Comment: It is a very big xml file, I'm only change a couple of values.

Comment: Thanks again. Although it is not a preferred solution.